# AppleSearchingAds: Why 'iad_attribution' is always 'true' for dev build?

Tags: ios, apple-search-ads

We're implementing Searching Ads attribution to the build to detect all users which installed the app by clicking Searching Ad from the Apple.

During testing, I have two problems which I cannot understand: 
 - case 1: I installed the build from Hockeyapp on the device where the user's never opened AppleSearch Ad >> the ads attribution API sent me 'iad_attribution': true parameter
 - I expect that the parameter should be 'false'

- case 2: I installed the same build on the device where the user's clicked on Search Ad 4 day before >> I receive parameters: 'iad_click_date = iad_conversion_date' which has the same value.
- I expect that the parameters should be 'iad_click_date = *4 day before date* & 'iad_conversion_date' = *the current date*

So, have you ever have the same problem? Maybe you know how it can be tested more effective? Or Apple always sent 'iad_attribution': true for not-published builds?

Answer (score 2):

For testing purposes, the `AdClient` framework always returns `true` for `iad_attribution` along with a set of dummy data.

You cannot disable this.

In production however, you will get `false` without data if the user has not clicked a Search Ads ad within the 30 days leading up to downloading your application.

The `AdClient` framework is not documented well, so I understand your confusion.

Comment: Same problem with `AAAttribution.attributionToken()`. HTTP payload is always true.